# Is "overflow hidden + javascript scrolling control" affect SEO

Tags: seo, javascript, css

I have an html page with a css `overflow:hidden` affected to `body`
My `<content>` is at `top:100%` positioned in absolute.
When I scroll, a javascript code change the `<content>` top position to simulate a scroll so I control where the user will land each time he use his mousewheel (I also do it for touch screens)

Will that badly affect my SEO? Or does google panda + rankbrain are smart enough to get it right?

Comment: I've run across a few sites that do that (usually news articles) and I always wonder why.   It is really confusing to me.  I don't usually end up reading those articles.  I certainly don't come back to those sites if I can remember which they are.   Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Except that it's not an article/blog page, it's a home page only composed with interest points. (like most of the fwa or awwward winners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess so don't hold me to it.

With tools such as SEMRush (Helps identify weaknesses in your sites SEO); I think this reads the page only up until you would be able to execute jQuery / JS. So whatever is on your page within the DOM on load - is what is read.

Having objects 'overflow: hidden;' isn't going to make a difference to your score.

So long as you are not spamming multiple H1's, or using things like 'display: none; & visibility: hidden;' on boxes filled with keywords. You should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it will affect it. Anything that comes after "hidden" will be weighted less, so you wanna avoid having keyword heavy stuff after "hidden".

Source: https://www.rebootonline.com/blog/hidden-text-experiment/

Comment: No, it doesn't work like this anymore. Your article is really old.